# Second drop-down options based on first drop-down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

On a web page, if you select different options on the first drop-down, different options will appear in the second drop-down.

```
<select id="independent">
  <option value="A"> A </option>
  <option value="B"> B </option>
</select>

<select id="dependent">
  <option value="A021">    A1 </option>
  <option value="A22019">  A2 </option>
  <option value="A3541">   A3 </option>
  <option value="B148">    B1 </option>
  <option value="B2">      B2 </option>
  <option value="B397415"> B3 </option>
</select>
```

Here is the jQuery I have so far:

```
$(function() {

    $('#independent').on('change', function (e) {
        var endingChar = $(this).val().split('').pop();
        var selected = $( '#independent' ).val();
          $('#dependent option[value^='+selected+']').toggle(endingChar == selected);
        $('#dependent').val('');
    })

});
```

What I am trying to do here is 
   1. Set variable *selected* to the value of the option selected in the first drop-down 
   2. Use that value to look through the **first letters** of the values of all of the second drop-down possibilities to **populate what I want to see in the second drop-down**

*However when I select anything from the first drop-down, all of the options (A1 through B3) appear in the second drop-down. What is wrong?*

Answer (score 1):

You could try like this.

First hide all the options and show only matching options using toggleClass()

```js
$(function() {

    $('#independent').on('change', function (e) {
    $('#dependent').val('');
        var endingChar = $(this).val().split('').pop();       
        var selected = $( '#independent' ).val();
          $('#dependent option').addClass('show');
 
          $('#dependent option[value^='+selected+']').toggleClass('show');
    })

});
```

```css
.show{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="independent">
  <option value="A"> A </option>
  <option value="B"> B </option>
</select>

<select id="dependent">
  <option value="A021">    A1 </option>
  <option value="A22019">  A2 </option>
  <option value="A3541">   A3 </option>
  <option value="B148">    B1 </option>
  <option value="B2">      B2 </option>
  <option value="B397415"> B3 </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Let's say I had 3 drop-downs, and the last drop-down was dependent on the first two. If i selected A in the first drop-down and B in the second drop-down, how could I make it so that the third drop-down had the values for A, and appended the values for B too?

Comment: isn't this answer helped you?

Comment: do the same thing for that one too

Comment: I'm not sure how to append values to a drop-down

Comment: just google it  _how to append values to a drop-down_

Comment: The results that come up show how to append one more option to a drop-down, but I don't want to do that for all of the possibilities. How would I code it so that it appends options dynamically based on the value attribute?

Comment: Good answer. +1

Comment: @Dineshundefined How to create Dependent Dropdown List? My code :: URL -> url-> paste.ofcode.org/3aduvzMEnLGEnEYVMbhUbT4    I need If the first dropdown "3 Compact " is selected second dropdown should not be able to select "3 Compact" & if first dropdown "5 Regular" is selected second dropdown should not be able to select below values of 5 Regular like "3 Compact, 3 Regular, 3 Triple, 5 Compact.
The logic is, if first dropdown value selects like 5, second dropdown value must select above 5 not 4 or 3 or 2 or 1.   I am not able to post as a new question, could you pls help me here?

Answer (score 1):

The following loops through the options. If the option's value doesn't start with the correct first letter, a class is added to hide via css. If it does match, the class is removed. It also selects the first option that matches the correct letter, so a hidden option isn't selected.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#independent').on('change', function (e) {

      var selected = $('#independent').val().toUpperCase();
      var currentDep = $('#dependent').val().charAt(0).toUpperCase();
      var changedSelected = false;

      $('#dependent option').each(function() {

        var opt = $(this);
        var value = opt.val().charAt(0).toUpperCase();

        if (value !== selected) {

          opt.addClass('hide');
          opt.removeAttr('selected');

        } else {

          opt.removeClass('hide');

          if (!changedSelected) {

            opt.attr('selected', 'selected');
            changedSelected = true;

          } else {
            opt.removeAttr('selected');
          }
        }
      });
    });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="independent">
  <option value="A"> A </option>
  <option value="B"> B </option>
</select>

<select id="dependent">
  <option value="A021">    A1 </option>
  <option value="A22019">  A2 </option>
  <option value="A3541">   A3 </option>
  <option value="B148">    B1 </option>
  <option value="B2">      B2 </option>
  <option value="B397415"> B3 </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
    $('#independent').on('change', function (e) {

      var selected = $('#independent').val().toUpperCase();
      var currentDep = $('#dependent').val().charAt(0).toUpperCase();
      var changedSelected = false;

      $('#dependent option').each(function() {

        var opt = $(this);
        var value = opt.val().charAt(0).toUpperCase();

        if (value !== selected) {

          opt.addClass('hide');
          opt.removeAttr('selected');

        } else {

          opt.removeClass('hide');

          if (!changedSelected) {

            opt.attr('selected', 'selected');
            changedSelected = true;

          } else {
            opt.removeAttr('selected');
          }
        }
      });
    });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="independent">
  <option value="A"> A </option>
  <option value="B"> B </option>
</select>

<select id="dependent">
  <option value="A021">    A1 </option>
  <option value="A22019">  A2 </option>
  <option value="A3541">   A3 </option>
  <option value="B148">    B1 </option>
  <option value="B2">      B2 </option>
  <option value="B397415"> B3 </option>
</select>
```

Comment: its working fine here but when i copy past this code in my system its not working the same way

Comment: even any other options with dropdowns not working. i mean if i comment the jquery code then even its same out put i can only see the dropdowns with list thats it. and with jquery even the same out. it seems jquery code is not effecting on dropdowns. any solutions?