# html select change options/values of another select using java script

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have two html select for example please see the below code.

```
<select class="select1" onchange='customJavascriptfuntion()'>
<option value='a'>a</option>
<option value='b'>b</option>
<option value='c'>c</option>
</select>


<select class="select2">
<option value='d'>d</option>
<option value='e'>e</option>
<option value='f'>f</option>

<option value='g'>g</option>
<option value='h'>h</option>
<option value='i'>i</option>
<option value='j'>j</option>
</select>
```

so I need a javascript function to change the options of second select depending on the first select, for example if I select "b" then it should show "g,h,i,j" options or if I select "c" then it should show options as "d,e,f" or if I select option "a" then it should show all options.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44712226/second-drop-down-options-based-on-first-drop-down
refer this link for your answer it might be help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Second drop-down options based on first drop-down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44712226/second-drop-down-options-based-on-first-drop-down)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres another native JS way, it would also be easy to convert this to jQuery if preferred.

```js
function customJavascriptfuntion(elm){
 // get select 2 (returns array so get first item)
 var select2 = document.getElementsByClassName('select2')[0];
 
 // get select 1 value
 var currentValue = elm.value;
 
 // create option arrays
 var optionB = ["g","h","i","j"]
 var optionC = ["d","e","f"]
 // combine both array options for full list
 var optionA = optionB.concat(optionC); 
 
 // depending on select 1 value populate select 2 values
 if(currentValue === "a")
  createOptions(optionA, select2)
 else if(currentValue === "b")
  createOptions(optionB, select2)
 else if(currentValue === "c")
  createOptions(optionC, select2)
}

// create options for select 2 (elm)
function createOptions(options, elm){
 // reset current options
 elm.innerHTML = "<option selected disabled>Select</option>";
 // loop through each option and create <option> element
 options.forEach(function(optionValue){
  // create option elm
  var opt = document.createElement('option');
  // set value
  opt.value = optionValue;
  // set inner html
  opt.innerHTML = optionValue;
  // add to the select box
  elm.add(opt)
 })
}
```

```html
<select class="select1" onchange='customJavascriptfuntion(this)'>
  <option selected disabled>Select</option>
  <option value='a'>a</option>
  <option value='b'>b</option>
  <option value='c'>c</option>
</select>


<select class="select2">
  <option selected disabled>Select</option>
</select>
```

Comment: does this code working in internet explorer @NickMcB ?, because when I run it in the internet explorer it is not working.

Comment: because the append is not supported by internet explorer

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out (sorry I dont have IE to test). Ive updated .appead() to .add() with is compatible with IE11+

Answer (score 0):

Doing in pure javascript. You can check the value on `onchange event` and add `options` accordingly.

```js
function customJavascriptfuntion(obj) {
  var select2 = document.getElementsByClassName("select2")[0];
  select2.innerHTML = "";
  if (obj.value == "a") {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = 'd';
    opt.innerHTML = 'd';
    select2.appendChild(opt);
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = 'e';
    opt.innerHTML = 'e';
    select2.appendChild(opt);
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = 'f';
    opt.innerHTML = 'f';
    select2.appendChild(opt);
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = 'g';
    opt.innerHTML = 'g';
    select2.appendChild(opt);
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = 'h';
    opt.innerHTML = 'h';
    select2.appendChild(opt);
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = 'i';
    opt.innerHTML = 'i';
    select2.appendChild(opt);
  }
  if (obj.value == "c") {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = 'd';
    opt.innerHTML = 'd';
    select2.appendChild(opt);
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = 'e';
    opt.innerHTML = 'e';
    select2.appendChild(opt);
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = 'f';
    opt.innerHTML = 'f';
    select2.appendChild(opt);
    
  }
  if (obj.value == "b") {
   
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = 'g';
    opt.innerHTML = 'g';
    select2.appendChild(opt);
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = 'h';
    opt.innerHTML = 'h';
    select2.appendChild(opt);
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = 'i';
    opt.innerHTML = 'i';
    select2.appendChild(opt);
  }

}
```

```html
<select class="select1" onchange='customJavascriptfuntion(this)'>
<option style="display:none">Select</option>
<option value='a'>a</option>
<option value='b'>b</option>
<option value='c'>c</option>
</select>


<select class="select2">

</select>
```